# Integration of trigonometric and logarithmic terms

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$I = \int\sin x \log_e(\sec x + \tan x) dx$$

My attempt:
$$\int \sin x \log_e(\sec x + \tan x) dx = \int\sin x\log_e(\frac{\sin x+1}{\cos x}) dx$$
$$\therefore I = \int \sin x\log_e(\sin x+1) dx - \int \sin 
x \log_e(\cos x) dx$$

I can solve the second integral but how do I go about solving the first one.

Comment: use integration by parts

Comment: Isn't there a solution that avoids integration by parts?

Comment: Maybe but you can use integration by parts from the start to get rid of the logarithm.  The last integral also leads to a very easy integral after applying IBP

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use integration by parts